# how to write a client side api in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, event-handling, client

I've written the server side of an api, that serves html via json using REST via codeigniter.
What I want to do next is write a client side api with javascript, to get the data from the server via the api, present it in the dom and bind events to it. Those events will then use the api to get new html, etc.

Now where do I begin? Can I use jquery in my api script and just do ajax calls to the api for every event triggered? Or are there better ways to do this?
Are there any js libraries that help me do this? I've taken a look at backbone and require, bot I'm not sure if this is the correct purpose for those libraries.

Comment: If you have to write a client application then Backbone is a good choice. If you just want to write Ajax calls and hook them to event handlers then jQuery would be a better choice.

Comment: thanks. I already use jQuery, but with a lot of events, the code gets messy quite easily. So if I would use jQuery, I would like to use a kind of api architecture that structures my events, calls and functions. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Then I suggest using the Backbone framework or another one. You can see a list of application frameworks here http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/

Answer (score 1):

**Use fetch method to call web API from client side**

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(json => console.log(json))
```